# Unison bidirectional sync - problem with set permissions?

Tags: permissions, unison

I have setup unison to sync a folder on two computers.
On the first one C1, the folder is inside Home. On the second one C2, the folder is on a partition, which is mounted automatically at startup.
Sincronization works, if the files change on C2 and are transferred to C1's home folder. When I manipulate the files on C1, they are not syncronized to the partition on C2. In Unison window asks for "prop ? prop". Afterwards files are not syncronized.
How do I have to set the permissions correctly?

Actual permissions are:
C1 Folder
Owner = User (create and delete)
Group = User (Access)
Others = (Access)

C2 Folder
Owner = root (create and delete)
Group = root (create and delete)
Others = (create and delete)

The partition on C2 has to be available for several user accounts.

Thanks and greetings